# Spring JdbcTokenStore doesn't store/ create tokens. (Failed to fetch token)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-jdbc, spring-oauth2

So I've been trying for over a week to get the JdbcTokenStore to work, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.
I'm not using spring boot and I'll try my best to explain what I'm doing.

So let's start with the database for the tokens:
I'm using PostgreSQL which is why I use `BYTEA`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oauth_client_details;
CREATE TABLE oauth_client_details (
  client_id               VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  resource_ids            VARCHAR(255),
  client_secret           VARCHAR(255),
  scope                   VARCHAR(255),
  authorized_grant_types  VARCHAR(255),
  web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(255),
  authorities             VARCHAR(255),
  access_token_validity   INTEGER,
  refresh_token_validity  INTEGER,
  additional_information  VARCHAR(4096),
  autoapprove             VARCHAR(255)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oauth_client_token;
CREATE TABLE oauth_client_token (
  token_id          VARCHAR(255),
  token             BYTEA,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name         VARCHAR(255),
  client_id         VARCHAR(255)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oauth_access_token;
CREATE TABLE oauth_access_token (
  token_id          VARCHAR(255),
  token             BYTEA,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name         VARCHAR(255),
  client_id         VARCHAR(255),
  authentication    BYTEA,
  refresh_token     VARCHAR(255)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oauth_refresh_token;
CREATE TABLE oauth_refresh_token (
  token_id       VARCHAR(255),
  token          BYTEA,
  authentication BYTEA
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oauth_code;
CREATE TABLE oauth_code (
  code           VARCHAR(255),
  authentication BYTEA
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oauth_approvals;
CREATE TABLE oauth_approvals (
  userId         VARCHAR(255),
  clientId       VARCHAR(255),
  scope          VARCHAR(255),
  status         VARCHAR(10),
  expiresAt      TIMESTAMP,
  lastModifiedAt TIMESTAMP
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ClientDetails;
CREATE TABLE ClientDetails (
  appId                  VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  resourceIds            VARCHAR(255),
  appSecret              VARCHAR(255),
  scope                  VARCHAR(255),
  grantTypes             VARCHAR(255),
  redirectUrl            VARCHAR(255),
  authorities            VARCHAR(255),
  access_token_validity  INTEGER,
  refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
  additionalInformation  VARCHAR(4096),
  autoApproveScopes      VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I'm also inserting the client_details:

```
INSERT INTO oauth_client_details (client_id, client_secret, scope, authorized_grant_types, web_server_redirect_uri, authorities, access_token_validity, refresh_token_validity,
                                  additional_information, autoapprove)
VALUES ('my-trusted-client', '$2a$04$Ovgng6BUO6tPPnZNkp8OuOjeBIM1mj5KVvo4r1a9Zh/py14yA0w9u', 'trust,read,write',
        'password,authorization_code,refresh_token', NULL, NULL, 36000, 36000, NULL, TRUE);
```

I'm using BCrypt which is why the password is encrypted in the insert. (password = secret)

**OAuth2SecurityConfig AKA WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hitmax.server")
@Order(1)
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


    private static String REALM = "MY_OAUTH_REALM";
    private final UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler, @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.userApprovalHandler = userApprovalHandler;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .resourceIds("my_rest_api")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .autoApprove(false)
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("$2a$04$Ovgng6BUO6tPPnZNkp8OuOjeBIM1mj5KVvo4r1a9Zh/py14yA0w9u")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM + "/client")
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }


}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Autowired
    TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().
                anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/protected/**")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
    
}
```

**Action1 :**

[image: action 1]

**Action2 : inserting credentials**

[image: action2]

**By reading the logs I can can confirm that it did found this user, also I see the authorize page**

[image: action3]

**So after pressing Authorize I see this in my restClient (Insomnia)**

[image: action 4]

I've been going through the logs. I'll post the entire log + the parts that seemed important to me.

**Full log**
https://pastebin.com/ALLLw8Ng

**important logs according to me**
**1**

```
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter - Getting access token for: my-trusted-client
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?]
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hitmaxServer]
22:18:54.657 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
22:18:54.657 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore - Failed to find access token for authentication org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@3aa38da: Principal: com.hitmax.server.mvc.dao.service.user.AuthenticationService$1@2dc4f5d4; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

**2**

```
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter - Getting access token for: my-trusted-client
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?]
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
22:18:54.580 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hitmaxServer]
22:18:54.657 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
22:18:54.657 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore - Failed to find access token for authentication org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@3aa38da: Principal: com.hitmax.server.mvc.dao.service.user.AuthenticationService$1@2dc4f5d4; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated! I'm kind of desperate now.

Comment: @cool Yes I've checked, it is completely empty in the database, however shouldn't it generate the token when a user is authenticated? The only table with preset data would be `oauth_client_details`, right?

Comment: yes. the token should have been created after the authentication and yes only initial data you need is in the oauth_client_details table

Comment: why is client secret "secret" in your restClient. shouldn't it be that cryptic long string you use?

Comment: @cool I checked the full log, but couldn't find an insert. As for the previous question: I've had the B Crypt since the beginning and didn't have any problem with authentication.  That cryptic long string is equal to "secret". I've used a BCrypt generator to get the encryption of "secret" and pasted it in the database.

Comment: I am not familiar with authorization  grant type as I usually used "password" and "client_credential" but if I understand it correctly from this link https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/authorization-code/ what you should get after authentication is not a token but an access code. After that you should make a call with that code to get a access token. I guess that is why we dont see it in the database.

Comment: @cool from the link you provided I was able to search the queries in order of the example: 1.`/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my-trusted-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F` You can see the logs here: https://pastebin.com/wAv8AuPR . For step 2 I found this in my logs: https://pastebin.com/1LbddN0z. step3 is something I couldn't find in my logs. My full logs: https://pastebin.com/ALLLw8Ng . Does this mean the authentication was successful? It does say in my logs that the authentication credentials are correct, but after I press the authorize button I get the error

Comment: yes it looks like authentication was fine and you were able to get the access code with the value "IR0NLp". But after that I guess either smth is wrong with redirection or smth is missing

Comment: can you try to make the call with the given curl example from the site just to see whether the token creation is working fine with the current config. If that is the case then you should change your code or redirection url.

Comment: @cool interesting. when I go to `http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my-trusted-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Foauth%2Ftoken` and I click authorize I get the follwing error: `{"error":"method_not_allowed","error_description":"Request method &#39;GET&#39; not supported"}` The url I get this error from is `http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?code=HDpd2r`

Comment: I was talking about this curl -u TestClient:TestSecret https://api.mysite.com/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=xyz  not the authorize. because we already know that it works.

Comment: @cool this is a bit odd. I just restarted the server and now this: `curl -u my-trusted-client:secret http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=BvWkQv'`  returns: a json {
 "error": "invalid_request",
 "error_description": "Missing grant type"
} the logs now say authorization successful and after that missing grant type.

Comment: Sorry oguzcan. I am done for today. but at least you know where the problem is. My suggestion would be try to make that request work first. Then fix your app. the last call you made looks like you couldn't send the proper rest call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after rewriting my code using https://github.com/adamzareba/company-structure-spring-security-oauth2-authorities as an guide. My current project looks as followed:

**ServerSecurityConfig AKA WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hitmax.server")
@Order(1)
@Import(Encoders.class)
public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // region: fields
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder;
    // endregion: fields

    // region: methods
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder);
    }
    // endregion: methods
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // region: fields
    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-server-rest-api";
    private static final String SECURED_READ_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('read')";
    private static final String SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('write')";
    private static final String SECURED_PATTERN = "/secured/**";
    // endregion: fields
    // region: methods
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(SECURED_PATTERN).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SECURED_PATTERN).access(SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE)
                .anyRequest().access(SECURED_READ_SCOPE);
    }
    // endregion: methods
}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // region: fields
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;

    // endregion: fields

    // region: methods
    // region: beans
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        String insertAccessTokenSql = "insert into oauth_access_token (token_id, token, authentication_id, email, client_id, authentication, refresh_token) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        String selectAccessTokensFromUserNameAndClientIdSql = "select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where email = ? and client_id = ?";
        String selectAccessTokensFromUserNameSql = "select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where email = ?";
        String selectAccessTokensFromClientIdSql = "select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where client_id = ?";
        String insertRefreshTokenSql = "insert into oauth_refresh_token (token_id, token, authentication) values (?, ?, ?)";

        JdbcTokenStore jdbcTokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        jdbcTokenStore.setInsertAccessTokenSql(insertAccessTokenSql);
        jdbcTokenStore.setSelectAccessTokensFromUserNameAndClientIdSql(selectAccessTokensFromUserNameAndClientIdSql);
        jdbcTokenStore.setSelectAccessTokensFromUserNameSql(selectAccessTokensFromUserNameSql);
        jdbcTokenStore.setSelectAccessTokensFromClientIdSql(selectAccessTokensFromClientIdSql);
        jdbcTokenStore.setInsertRefreshTokenSql(insertRefreshTokenSql);


        return jdbcTokenStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    // endregion: beans
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
    // endregion: methods
}
```

Whil this setup still didn't work, I got more info trough the logs then usual. In the logs I read that my model Role had to be Serializable. This is because my User model has a many to one relationship with Role. (User was already Serialized) So I had 2 options 1: `@JsonIgnore` roles in User or 2. add Serializable to Role.

Another big change was to edit the `JdbcTokenStore` queries using the setters.

**Final word**

So the reason why the tokens weren't stored in the database:
 1. User had a relationship mapped to roles, which meant that Role's also had to be `Serializable`.
 2. (extra, because this wouldn't be needed if I used the preset database structure) Rewriting the preset queries in `JdbcTokenStore` to match my database tables.

All of this also explains why the authorization key was generated, but never stored in the database.